# Search for particular file type in a particular website

Tags: file-format, google-search

How can I search for particular type of files (i.e. PDF) from a website? Can I use Google to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use Google Search. In your case, you will want to use the `site:` and `filetype:` search operators. For example,

```
site:google.com filetype:pdf
```

will search `google.com` for PDF files.

---

**More information:**

- [site operator](https://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861)
- [filetype operator](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35287)